# Can't start a python console in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

OS:win7 x64

When I click the "python console" tab, I get the following output.
I had successfully started the python console several months ago, but now I can't.

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py" 52527 52528
PyDev console: starting.
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['D:\\2017编程\\python', 'D:/2017编程/python'])
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 257, in add_exec
    self.finish_exec(more)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 434, in finish_exec
    return server.NotifyFinished(more)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1112, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1452, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1154, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in single_request
    http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1279, in send_request
    self.send_content(connection, request_body)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1309, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] 由于目标计算机积极拒绝，无法连接。
```

Finally Solved.
Add the following to your hosts if you use a local DNS server.

```
::1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Comment: use translation tool and see what error you are getting maybe?

Comment: Translation: Because the target computer actively refused, unable to connect. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7070

Comment: Reboot the computer  recently?

Comment: @Scriptable THX! I use my local DNS server recently.

Comment: so did this fix the issue?

Comment: @Scriptable Yes, it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people have reported a similar issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7070

To quote the answer:

> User was able to fix the problem by changing the DNS server from the
>   local one (provided by the access point) to Google DNS server
>   (8.8.8.8).
>
> It looks like Mac OS Lion and later doesn't use /etc/hosts file first,
>   giving priority to DNS servers, hence it's possible that localhost may
>   not resolve (though, it's unclear why it doesn't fall back to
>   /etc/hosts).